# NO WIFI in settings ubuntu 20.04(there is no wifi)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, iwlwifi

I had a dual boot and then I disable dual boot. I started use only Ubuntu. I am using wifi for 5 minutes then ubuntu started to freeze , after that my wifi gone. I had already reinstall Ubuntu 3-4 times and result is the same . I used my wifi during first 5 minutes or 10 minutes and then it suddenly gone and also it is gone from settings there is no wifi part of settings. and also I tried all the commands like apt-get network-manager restart or smth other commands it does not help me one of them helped me and then wifi gone again after 10 minutes.PLease help me..

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:`

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
0: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

output of  `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

```
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”
```

I used `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and also `dmesg | grep iwl` they did not give any output and then I write only lspci here output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

and then I wrote again `dmesg | grep iwl` and there is no output again.

there is no output for `dmesg | grep -i sdio` but output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3496 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `dmesg | grep ath`

```
[    5.606713] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   70.206540] audit: type=1107 audit(1595153884.604:47): pid=705 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.18" pid=1556 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=706 peer_label="unconfined"
[   70.530885] audit: type=1107 audit(1595153884.927:48): pid=705 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1556 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=724 peer_label="unconfined"
[   70.531386] audit: type=1107 audit(1595153884.927:49): pid=705 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1556 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=724 peer_label="unconfined"
[   70.772057] audit: type=1107 audit(1595153885.166:50): pid=705 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1556 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=724 peer_label="unconfined"
[   70.774112] audit: type=1107 audit(1595153885.170:51): pid=705 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1556 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=724 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added output of command

Comment: You have a problem in a conf file. Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: @Pilot6 I added output of command

Comment: Remove this `“options iwlwifi disable_msix=1”` from the file, reboot and run again `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and also `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: If the first command doesn'r give any output then run `lspci`

Comment: @Pilot6 <code>rm options iwlwifi disable_msix=1</code> it says no such file or directory how can I remove it ? sorry I am new in ubuntu

Comment: Please don't add `<code>` tags. They don't work here. You need to run `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, edit the file, save it by Ctrl+O and exit by Ctrl+X.

Comment: @Pilot6 I removed “options iwlwifi disable_msix=1” from file and I did your says

Comment: I don't see any wireless devices there. Are you using a USB device? Please add output of `lsusb`?

Comment: Also please add output of `dmesg | grep -i sdio`. We need to find it somewhere.

Comment: @Pilot6 No I am not using usb device. but When I install ubuntu I used usb device but now there is no usb device. I added output of command

Comment: @Pilot6 And also I wanto note that I am using ethernet.(with cable)

Comment: According to `13d3:3496 IMC Networks` you have a QCA Wi-Fi+BT adapter. But it is not seen in `lspci`. Check if it is not disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep ath` then.

Comment: If it is not disabled there, I am afraid it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Instead of using `<code>` select the text and click `{}` icon above. I think it is a hardware problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 everything is enabled also ipv6 or ipv4. Thank you very much your answers.